# Xcode debug console with colors for default logs

Tags: xcode, debugging, colors, console

Is there a way to color the default output of the debug console in Xcode?
I was using SenTestCase and the log is difficult to read.

I know that there are projects like [LumberJack](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaLumberjack) and [XcodeColors](https://github.com/robbiehanson/XcodeColors) but they let you put colors to your own output, not the default.

Answer (score 2):

Xcode 4 lets you change the color for different types of console output. Just go to the Fonts & Colors section of the preferences and click on the "Console" tab:

[image: Xcode colors preferences]

That may or may not be what you're looking for... you can change the color of debugger output for easier reading, for example, but you don't get to assign different colors to specific categories of output messages.

Comment: Yes, I was trying that too, but is not really useful.